# How can I use jQuery maphilight?

Tags: jquery

I need an interactive map in my WordPress blog and would like to use jQuery *maphilight*.

I tested maphilight in a HTML file and it works great, but I want to use it in WordPress, so need to call the JS files and write some code like I used in the HTML file. How can I do this?

Here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jq/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jq/jquery.maphilight.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#ImageMap1').maphilight();
    });
</script>

<img id="ImageMap1" src="jq/cc.jpg" border="0" width="1212" height="812" orgWidth="1212" orgHeight="812" usemap="#image-maps-2015-12-08-070211" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2015-12-08-070211" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2015-12-08-070211">
    <area shape="rect" coords="1210,810,1212,812" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" />
    <area  alt="as" title="as" href="http://www.image-maps.com/as" shape="poly" coords="50,312,369,318,368,494,37,487" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
    <area  alt="ad" title="ad" href="http://www.image-maps.com/ad" shape="poly" coords="358,512,38,507,47,578,351,572" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
    <area  alt="aa" title="aa" href="http://www.image-maps.com/aa" shape="poly" coords="971,67,393,48,376,809,965,806" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
</map>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to write your own plugin for this. It wouldn't be very hard.

Comment: Specific integration of thrid party software is not on topic here. You should also try using the build in site search functionality as there are many examples of how to add scripts to to WordPress. It is as easy as using `wp_enqueue_script()` in the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

Comment: This can be rephrased as "How do I put a script and template inside a post/page?". The question as it's currently written implies this isn't a WordPress question but a Javascript question, hence the downvotes and close votes

Answer (score 1):

You could use this as a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). Put this in your content.

```
[maphilight]
```

[Register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) the shortcode.

```
// Add Shortcode
function maphilight_shortcode() { ?>

<img id="ImageMap1" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/jq/cc.jpg'; ?>" border="0" width="1212" height="812" orgWidth="1212" orgHeight="812" usemap="#image-maps-2015-12-08-070211" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2015-12-08-070211" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2015-12-08-070211">
    <area shape="rect" coords="1210,810,1212,812" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" />
    <area  alt="as" title="as" href="http://www.image-maps.com/as" shape="poly" coords="50,312,369,318,368,494,37,487" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
    <area  alt="ad" title="ad" href="http://www.image-maps.com/ad" shape="poly" coords="358,512,38,507,47,578,351,572" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
    <area  alt="aa" title="aa" href="http://www.image-maps.com/aa" shape="poly" coords="971,67,393,48,376,809,965,806" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
</map>
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/jq/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'; ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/jq/jquery.maphilight.js'; ?>"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#ImageMap1').maphilight();
    });
</script>

<?php
}

add_shortcode( 'maphilight', 'maphilight_shortcode' );
```

Note: This code isn't tested and was generated with [GenerateWP](https://generatewp.com/shortcodes/).

If you don't use shortcodes then you can always add scripts with [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and construct a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) to display code

Comment: Shortcode should never go into `functions.php`. Shortcodes are meant for plugins, not themes

Comment: If you add `[maphiligh']` in a post/page, and you change themes, your page will output  `[maphilight]` as the shortcode does not exist anymore. Any type of function that add functionality to the site should never go into a theme as features like custom post types, custom taxonomies and shortcodes would stop working if themes are changed

Comment: You just need to use a child theme so you won't lose the shortcode when you update your theme.